# Joomla Component that allows frontend-access to a single folder

Tags: joomla, ftp, file-management

working on a Joomla site I came across the following problem: I need to give frontend-access to a specified directory on the server. The user (an elderly man who is not into IT, should be as simple as possible!) has to upload photos into a directory and should also be able to delete them if he wishes. I have found several extensions that allow easy uploading from the frontend. Still, I did not find any which would also allow to delete content, in fact I haven't even found one that even displays the content of the folder.

The features I ideally would like to have are:
- uploading
- displaying in a list
- deleting out of that list
the content of a specified folder via front-end.

Does anyone know an extension providing the needed features? Or would there possibly be a solution combining multiple extensions, each of them fulfilling one of the needs?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

the Image Galery of the DOCman extension (https://www.joomlatools.com) should do the job but it is not free...
Regards

Comment: hum that's pretty expensive for a single use, I'm not a professional. But I have seen there are several other (free) galleries that also offer uploading and deletion of single pictures, that will probably do the job too if i can simplify it